# PUT - Web API controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api, put, spdy

I have a put method inside my web API controller. The site has a view mode and an edit mode. When the user is in Edit mode it should save the data into the database(because there are currency changes). When the user is on the view mode page it will still calculate the currency changes but it shouldn't be saved into the database.

So inside my method I have a condition in which mode the user is. When it is edit mode it should calculate and save it. When the user is in view mode it only should calculate it and return the object so I can use it client side.

```
if (isEditMode)
 {
    _currencyConversionService.ApplyCurrencyRateToCarearRequest(request);
                _requestRepository.Save(request);
 }
 else
 {
     _currencyConversionService.ApplyCurrencyRateToCarearRequest(request);
 }

  return Ok(request);
```

In edit mode the data is saved when the user clicks the confirmation button. But I'm getting an error clientside though:

**net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

Is this because I just return the request inside the Ok() that i'm getting this error or why do I get this one? I'm ending up into the catch from this code:

```
this.service.save(this.model, this.isEditMode)
                .then((response: any) => {
                    debugger;


        this.messageService.success('request.notifications.currencySaved');
                    this.close();
                    this.$timeout(() => {
                        this.$window.location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                }).
                catch((reason: any) => {
                    debugger;
                });
```

How can I return an object inside a PUT method?

Thanks, Brent

Comment: This is not a Web API issue. SPDY is a Google protocol that is now deprecated. See [here](http://techdows.com/2015/08/fix-chromes-err_spdy_protocol_error.html) for how to fix this error in Chrome (which I assume is your client). Or update Chrome to the latest version.

Comment: I have the latest version of Chrome installed and it is still the same.

Comment: Are you using Avast? And/or connecting via HTTPS? If so have you tried the fixes [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sfAqeo4hDy8)?

Comment: I found why it was giving this error. I forgot the map the entity before returning it inside the response. So I was giving a full entity instead of a readmodel. Thanks for the help though!